# user permissions on mysql db user

Tags: mysql, sql, database, phpmyadmin, phpbb3

I created a forum on my site using my my website provider, it created the database for me and uploaded the forum, etc. Previously I uploaded the forum and created the db myself but for some reason the releases of *phpbb3* are riddled with stuff like missing `?>` tags

I'm trying to connect to the db using my own script, I have a few other databases which I created, and they work fine, except this one which was made by my provider

```
$con = mysql_connect('ip','user','pass');
if (!$con) {
    die('Not connected : ' . mysql_error());
}

$db_selected = mysql_select_db('forum',$con);
if (!$db_selected) {
    die ('Can\'t use db : ' . mysql_error());
}
```

I get `Can't use db : Access denied for user 'user'@'%' to database 'forum'`

EDIT: (fixed) was missing variable named $db_selected

Comment: Are you running this script on the same server the forum runs on?

Comment: @Andy yes. im trying to connect to the database, and show news articles on my website (index) from under `phpbb3_posts`

Comment: I also switched databases for forums (i created it this time) to see if it would change(uploaded all previous data), still get same error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that the user you want to use to access the database is called "user", check the following

1) Switch current db to mysql, and check if the user exists (there is a row having Host = % in the results of the following query)

```
USE mysql;
SELECT * FROM user WHERE user = 'user'
```

2) Check if this user has permissions for the database (there is a row having Db = database and host = %)

```
SELECT * FROM db WHERE user = 'user'
```

3) If this looks fine, try to flush privileges by the following:

```
FLUSH PRIVILEGES;
```

Then try to log in .. it may help.

The full step by step how to create a user and grant privileges is here:

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/adding-users.html